# How do I install the nagios NRPE plugin on CentOS 5 using yum?

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, nagios, nrpe

How do I install the nagios NRPE plugin on CentOS 5 using yum?

I've tried `yum install nagios-plugins` but it's only downloading a fraction of a megabyte. Then if I do a search for one of the commands that was supposed to be installed, like `check_users` nothing comes up. When I look in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` I'm only seeing three files

```
CentOS-Base.repo
CentOS-Media.repo
EPEL.repo
```

Do i need to add a source? If so, which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually fixed this by installing RPMforge, which just so happens to aim at DAG repository, and then all yum commands to install nagios worked great.

Try `yum remove nagios-nrpe` (etc), then see [this page](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge#head-5aabf02717d5b6b12d47edbc5811404998926a1b), install the update, then try the command `yum install nagios-nrpe` again and see if that works.